# trouble installing Fiona in python cpl_error.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, geospatial, ogr, fiona, geopandas

I have tried to install geopandas two different ways: `pip install geopandas` or by cloning

```
git clone https://github.com/kjordahl/geopandas
```

In both cases, the installation file `setup.py` runs for a while and then returns this error message:

```
src/fiona/ogrinit.c:300:23: fatal error: cpl_error.h: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

[`fiona`](https://pypi.org/project/Fiona/) is interface to [OGR](https://gdal.org/programs/index.html#vector-programs) so Python can read geospatial data.  `cpl_error.h` seems to be missing.  What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try installing gdal dev binaries with:

```
sudo apt install libgdal-dev
```

and fiona later on:

```
sudo pip install fiona
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev` ✓

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) on OSX:

Run`brew install gdal` before running `pip install fiona`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal and download the (fiona).whl file

> pip install C:\Users\Downloads\Fiona-1.8.4-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

If you encounter error then read below

download the correct version of fiona else you will an error
`Fiona-1.8.4-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl` is not a supported wheel on this platform.**

to know which version is supported 
Use the below command in the python ide

```
**import pip._internal;**
**print(pip._internal.pep425tags.get_supported())**

output:- [('cp36', 'cp36m', 'win_amd64'), ('cp36', 'none', 'win_amd64'), ('py3', 'none', 'win_amd64'), ('cp36', 'none', 'any'), ('cp3', 'none', 'any'), ('py36', 'none', 'any'), ('py3', 'none', 'any'), ('py35', 'none', 'any'), ('py34', 'none', 'any'), ('py33', 'none', 'any'), ('py32', 'none', 'any'), ('py31', 'none', 'any'), ('py30', 'none', 'any'
```

choose the **cp(version)** which is mentioned in the output