# error installing fiona in OSX 10.9

Tags: python, macos, gdal, shapely, fiona

I am having difficulty with installing fiona.

I have followed fiona's official documentation ( https://github.com/sgillies/fiona)  as well as the related thread below.

[trouble installing Fiona in python cpl_error.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19883315/trouble-installing-fiona-in-python-cpl-error-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

I had no trouble with pip install shapely and I used brew install gdal.  When I use the command pip install fiona I get a number of errors

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]

clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future

error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

as well as warnings with regards to gdal-config such as `"Failed to get options via gdal-config"`

I am worried there is an issue with gdal-config's location thats causing the issue. I think I might have had GDAL previously installed with kyngchaos for QGIS use a while ago before I used the brew install

Any insights would be much appreciated. I can't imagine I am the only one who has had issues installing fiona, but I haven't been able to find a resolution through google searching alone yet.

Comment: Are you using XCode 5.1? If so, this could be the problem / solution: http://bruteforce.gr/bypassing-clang-error-unknown-argument.html

Comment: That worked! thank you for ending my headache!! such a simple solution.

Comment: No problem, I've added it as a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using XCode 5.1, the problem is likely unrecognised options in Clang. See here for details on how to fix this: http://bruteforce.gr/bypassing-clang-error-unknown-argument.html